# clr stored procedures with two in parameters

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0, clr, sqlclr

I have started to learn clr stored procedures. I have managed to one work with one singel stored procedure. But when I attempt to create a stored procedure with two in parameters I run into strange results. When I supply the two parameters I am getting the total of all rows available, and not the rows supposed to be matched with parameter pair.

The two parameters in my actual table, tblRoute are named DepCity and ArvCity both with datatype nvarchar50.

I do understand that this current complexity should be rather solved in sql server itself, but this is a training exercise for clr stored procedures on my part.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void RouteSqlStoredProcedure(SqlString strDepCity, SqlString strArvCity)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Context Connection=true";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblAirline.AirlineName, tblAircraft.Manufacturer, tblAircraft.AircraftModel, tblAircraft.AircraftUnits, tblAircraft.SeatCapacity, tblAircraft.TotalCapacity, tblRoute.FlightNr, tblRoute.DepCity, tblRoute.ArvCity FROM tblAircraft INNER JOIN tblAircraftRoute ON tblAircraft.AircraftID = tblAircraftRoute.AircraftID INNER JOIN tblAirline ON tblAircraft.AirlineID = tblAirline.AirlineID INNER JOIN tblRoute ON tblAircraftRoute.RouteID = tblRoute.RouteID";

    SqlParameter paramDep = new SqlParameter("@strDepCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    paramDep.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; // optional as it is the default
    paramDep.Value = strDepCity.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDep);

    SqlParameter paramArr = new SqlParameter("@strArvCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    paramArr.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; // optional as it is the default
    paramArr.Value = strArvCity.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramArr);
    SqlDataReader sqldr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(sqldr);

    sqldr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using either of the parameters in the query itself. SQL Server cannot determine how supplied parameters should be used in a query. You need to add the proper `WHERE` condition to the query and reference those parameters.